# Generate a column based on incolumn constraints

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a dataframe having 2 columns :

```
F_Date     Count
01/09/2019  1421
01/09/2019  1421
01/09/2019  1421
01/09/2019  1421
01/09/2019  1421
01/09/2019  1421
01/09/2019  1421
01/09/2019  1421
01/09/2019  1421
01/09/2019  1421
01/09/2019  1421
01/09/2019  1421
01/09/2019  1421
01/09/2019  1421
01/09/2019  1421
01/09/2019  1421
01/09/2019  1421
01/09/2019  1421
01/09/2019  1421
```

I want to create a new column date_2 such that for 1/5th count values (in our example i.e. 1421 *20), we have F_date + 1 and for 2/5th count values, we have F_Date + 2, and other 1/5th value we have F_date + 3, and last 1/5th value we have F_Date + 4.

for our example, the output would be

1421/5 = 284.2 (round of to nearest i.e. 284) entries should have F_Date + 1
1421/5 = 284 * 2 = 568 entries should have F_Date + 2

1421/5 = 284 entries should have F_Date + 3

1421/5 = 284 + 1(Since 1 would remain after round off) should have F_Date + 4

**Expected output columns**

```
F_Date     Count    Date_2
```

Can anyone help with the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

old_df = pd.DataFrame({'F_Date': ["01/09/2019" for _ in range(1421)],
                   "Count": [1421 for _ in range(1421)]})

def split_dates(old):
    df = old.copy()
    df["Date_2"] = np.where((df.index//(df["Count"]//5)).astype(int)<4,
                            (df.index//(df["Count"]//5)).astype(int),
                            4)
    df["F_Date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["F_Date"],format="%M/%d/%Y")
    df["Date_2"] = df["F_Date"]+pd.to_timedelta(df["Date_2"], 'd')
    return df

new_df = split_dates(old_df)

print (new_df)
#
                  F_Date  Count              Date_2
0    2019-01-09 00:01:00   1421 2019-01-09 00:01:00
1    2019-01-09 00:01:00   1421 2019-01-09 00:01:00
2    2019-01-09 00:01:00   1421 2019-01-09 00:01:00
3    2019-01-09 00:01:00   1421 2019-01-09 00:01:00
4    2019-01-09 00:01:00   1421 2019-01-09 00:01:00
...                  ...    ...                 ...
1416 2019-01-09 00:01:00   1421 2019-01-13 00:01:00
1417 2019-01-09 00:01:00   1421 2019-01-13 00:01:00
1418 2019-01-09 00:01:00   1421 2019-01-13 00:01:00
1419 2019-01-09 00:01:00   1421 2019-01-13 00:01:00
1420 2019-01-09 00:01:00   1421 2019-01-13 00:01:00

[1421 rows x 3 columns]

print (new_df.groupby(["Date_2"]).count())
#
                     F_Date  Count
Date_2                            
2019-01-09 00:01:00     284    284
2019-01-10 00:01:00     284    284
2019-01-11 00:01:00     284    284
2019-01-12 00:01:00     284    284
2019-01-13 00:01:00     285    285
```

Comment: Thank you for your post, however the output needs to be new dataframe having all the columns as they were and an added column date_2 in the dataset. Can you please edit your answer for the same. It would really be helpful.

Comment: Sure. Just wrap them in a function and return the df should be fine.